# How to uninitialize weavy app instance in angular/ionic 6 for chat application?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I have created a chat application using weavy. I have successfully created  apps in weavy for group chat but when I open any of the new apps (for the group chat), I get an error

```
"weavy.fetch: request failed! Access denied for app G-2-207111852-left."
```

and

```
"WeavyApp.fetchOrCreate() Access denied for app G-2-207111852-left."
```

I want to uninitialize the first open app when user navigates to another page